# Error vs mistake and transmission vs transfer

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I original message:

> Create a log file when mistakes occurred during transmission data
>   between device and PC

I think this wrong and should be:

> Create a log file when errors occurred during data transfer between
>   device and PC

Can you prove/correct it?

Comment: I would say that errors are more formal and relate to procedures and technical concepts. Mistakes are made by people. In this context errors occur, so you are correct with that part.

Comment: Transmissions relate more to the carrier of information than the information or data "transmitted". So data would be more adequate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a native speaker, but even though your version of the sentence seems better, "occurred" sounds off to me, I'd go with

> Create a log file when errors occur during data transfer between device and PC

As a rule of thumb, computers do not make mistakes. "Error" is always correct when talking about computers.

As for "Transmission" vs "Transfer", the latter sounds better to my developer's ears.